# Routing/Page Rendering Issue with Return View()

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm having a weird issue with the MVC `return View()` and I'm not sure what is causing it and why as I have done plenty of `return View("ViewName", model)` throughout this project.

On going to the page a call is made to the database, everything is mapped correctly and passed to the view as I would expect.

```
public ActionResult ManageAccount()
{
    var user = UserRepository.GetById(WebUserSecurity.CurrentUserId);
    var model = Mapper.Map<Customer, ManageViewModel>(user);

    return View("ManageAccount", model);
}
```

However, if for whatever reason I need to return to the view (e.g. ModelState is invalid) I am passed back to a `400 Bad Request` page. I have stepped through each stage of the process and I know I am hitting the ManageAccount view but for some unknown reason that's not the view which is being rendered.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ManageAccount(ManageViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // DO SOME STUFF HERE
    }

    return View("ManageAccount", model);
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageAccount", "Account", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerId)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    // RENDER SOME HTML HTML HERE
}
```

I'm guessing this is a routing issue, but I am not sure how to go about fixing the problem in the current version of code. My next course of action is just to do a form update using JQuery Validation and an AJAX call. However, this is a hack around and I want to understand why this is happening as I may run into this problem in the future and not have the luxury of utilising AJAX.

If anyone needs any further information, please leave a comment and I'll update the question.

Comment: instead return View("ManageAccount", model); try using return redirecttoaction("ManageAccount")

Comment: Whilst I agree this kind of resolves the issue, it isn't a complete fix. There are places within the code where I need to do additional ModelState checks which cannot be accomplished through Data Annotations, therefore doing a RedirectToAction removes all the error messages I need to pass through to the view. In addition, it destroys all the data the user has entered as it is overwritten by a fresh call to the database, in turn an element of user friendliness is removed from the website. These two reasons are why I was using `return View("ViewName", model)`.

Comment: i can just give you a solution  to intact model ie model values will not lost ........

Comment: Feel free, I'll have a look at it and review the answer, if it works and is appropriate to retaining system functionality I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: When you do the POST in the form, does it enters in the ManageAccount(ManageViewModel model) action? If not it is probably because your Post does not include all ManageViewModel parameters...

Comment: 400: Bad Request generally means that the data sent by the client was malformed so it might be something to do with your model. The code you have shown works fine so the problem is elsewhere (although you can simplify it with `return View(model)` since the view name matches the method name)

Comment: I used to write the code along the lines of `return View(model)` but recently we've started implemented Unit Testing and from what I've read and tested the View Name needs to be in the return part of the code for the test/s to pass. Regarding your comment, I do have one inclination as to what may be causing the issue so I'll have a look to see if the View Models in question are rendering correctly.

Comment: Using Fiddler can help track down the errors, and if you Google "Troubleshoot 400 Bad Request" you will find plenty of possible causes.

Comment: @DaniCE To be honest, the only code in the action at the moment is the `return View();`. I did think what you were thinking, however after redefining model into a new ManageViewModel and passing the modelstate in manually, I still come up against the same error.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to be totally sure that it fits the method. You just need a breakpoint...

Comment: I've added a partial answer to the question, for those that are interested.

Comment: The final working solution has been added (turned out to be a 2 second fix in the end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... After a day of looking into this issue I finally found the route cause (kind of). I didn't want to go down the AJAX route with the database updates so I have continued to endeavour and rectify/understand the problem.

My last ditch effort was to remove the functionality out of the 'AccountsController' and put it somewhere else (HomeController) to eliminate the possibility that code specific to this controller was affecting the expected results.

The `return View("ViewName", model)` now works as anticipated. Now the next task is to track down why AccountsController is acting differently to HomeController with regards to ManageAccount when both actions inherit from the same classes.

**EDIT - THE SOLUTION**

The below link resolved the problem:

[Git Hub Answer](https://gist.github.com/remi/929007)

Our code redirects to an IIS or Custom errors page via the web.config file. The code had everything needed if we threw an HttpNotFound or Server Error. However, it was missing the existingResponse configuration within the httpErrors section of the error handling. Without this little bit of code it wasn't allowing me to pass custom error messages through and instead redirected the user to a 'Bad Request' page.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough">
    // Error Pages here
</httpErrors>
```

Adding in existingResponse has fixed the problem and left the rest of the application in full working order. I believe this has only recently been noticed as the web.config was only recently configured to work in this manor, regarding error pages and hadn't been spotted until I started doing some additional testing.

I appreciate the help provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that probably your ManageViewModel contains fields that are not included in the HTTP post, and for that reason the Action is not called (you can inspect the post fields using tools like firebug).

I will recommend that the post action only includes the fields that need to be edited, something like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ManageAccount(string name)
{

    var user = UserRepository.GetById(WebUserSecurity.CurrentUserId);
    var model = Mapper.Map<Customer, ManageViewModel>(user);

    // model updates:    
    model.Name = name;

    //validation checks...
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Name)) {
       //add model error
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
     return View(model);
    }

    // save changes...

    return View(model);
}
```

this way it will be more clear what data are you editing and your viewModel can have "show only" data  without the need to post it to match the controller parameters.

Comment: There was one item in the view model which was inheriting data from another model (ManageAccountPassword). I stripped this out and any other code linked to it in the view and I am still coming across the same problem. Even remapping a fresh set of Database data in the HTTPPOST produces the same the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I can only repeat the recommendation in the answer

Comment: Which is a fair comment, I'll endeavour to look into this and in the event I find an answer I'll try and post it for future reference.